# Magento 2 multi store setup and language selection screen

Tags: magento2, multistore

We have an installation with 4 websites, each is meant for different market / language. We also have 4 landing pages in different domains and from those we need to be able to link customers directly to the correct websites in Magento.

None of the 4 websites in Magento is "main" website. So I was thinking if we could have each presented in subfolder like www.example.com/fr and www.example.com/de
Could there be a language selection page/screen in the main www.example.com url where customer could select the correct website manually by clicking big country flags? How should I set this up? Do I need fifth website set up that only has the home page set up with those flags?

I'm also thinking automatic IP based redirection, but that might be a bit difficult if we want to link directly to the correct website.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make one website as a default one. From there, you will have a drop down from where user can choose the store or views. There you can do some modifications like when users choose stores or views, redirect to their websites.

One suggestion I will give is to use GeoIp location also. By this, depending on the location of the user, it will be automatically redirected.